# How to parse dictionary<string,string> in c#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

i have a dictionary in c# where i collect information as key value pair.
how i can parse them and get the value form them.

like key = "SID"  how i can get the value from dictionary by check the index by the key

Comment: What is this question asking?  You don't 'parse' dictionaries.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have indices either, they have keys.

Comment: You **access the Value** in a Dictionary by its **Key** using square brackets. `val = dict[key]`

Comment: Did you take a look into the class documentation? Did you read a basic example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As above but I would verify that they key you are looking for exists. I have done it in a simple way for readability.

```
        var keyToLookUp = "SomeText";
        string value;

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(keyToLookUp))
        {
            value = dictionary[keyToLookUp];
        }
        else
        {
            //Handle key not found here.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a dictionary MyDictionary then you can get the value for a key with this syntax:

object x = MyDictionary["SID"]

of course, x can be a more specific type than "object".

Answer (score 0):

`value = my_dict["SID"];` ...?

Answer (score 0):

```
 string value = dict[key]
```

In your case, `key` would be `"SID"`'  It's really that simple.

> like key = "SID" how i can get the value from dictionary **by check the index** by the key

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking there, but a Dictionary is an associative collection.  If you need to use/keep track of indices then you should use a different data structure.